# Bitbucket pipelines - SCP Deployment- Failing "Identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa_tmp not accessible: No such file or directory."

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to add bitbucket pipelines to deploy my angular application to one of our servers.

I configured SSH on my server and I could fetch the Host's finger print under Known hosts in Bitbucket

Below is my YAML file.

```
image: node:14

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Building Test angular application
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - echo "npm install in progress.."
            - npm install
            - echo "Installing angular/cli..."
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
            - echo "Starting the Build process.."
            - ng build
          artifacts:
            - dist/** # Save build for next steps
      - step:
          name: "Deployment"
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.3
              variables:
                USER: $USER
                SERVER: $SERVER
                REMOTE_PATH: '/c/testscp/'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'dist/*'
                SSH_KEY: $MY_SSH_KEY
```

The first step is running fine without any issues and I can see dist folder being added to the artifact however the second step is failing with the below error.

```
scp -rp -i /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa_tmp dist/TestPipelineApplication <<USER>>@<<SERVERIP>>:/c/testscp/
Warning: Identity file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/ssh/id_rsa_tmp not accessible: No such file or directory.
Load key "/root/.ssh/pipelines_id": invalid format
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
<<USER>>@<<SERVERIP>>: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

I never configured pipelines before so I am not completely sure what I am missing here.

Also, I looked into the below documentation but of no luck

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/scp-deploy/src/1.0.1/README.md

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*I know this issue is old but I hope this helps anyone in the same position as me when I copied the same error message into Google:*

I ran into the exact same issue and unfortunately due to very confusing documentation with regards to Pipelines and their configuration, this required a lot of trial and error.

One of the first things to do is simplify your YAML script:

```
    - step:
        name: Deployment
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/scp-deploy:0.3.3
            variables:
              USER: $USER
              SERVER: $SERVER
              REMOTE_PATH: '/c/testscp/'
              LOCAL_PATH: 'dist/*'
```

You needn't link the SSH within the YAML itself but within the repository's settings.

To do this you need to generate an SSH key pair in **Repository settings/Pipelines/SSH Keys**

This is where I got very confused as I had attempted to use the same key pair I had generated to access my host, which proved very difficult to configure. I found a very useful article written by Manuel Bosi [here](https://dev.to/manuelbosi/bitbucket-pipelines-configure-ssh-keys-1l56) which was very easy to follow and essentially got me to the point of having a key pair and the repo identifying my host server.

The next step was to copy the public key generated onto the host server.

All SSH keys (on Linux anyway) are stored in the file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. And the way this file is formatted is that each line is a different key specification and empty lines and those starting with # are ignored and treated as comments. You can read more about the full formatting options [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=daemon-format-authorized-keys-file).

So it was just a case of copying the public key from Bitbucket into a new line on this file and Voila! The SCP pipe was authenticated and and order was restored.

For me this was the start of my CI/CD journey and I'm very excited at the potential automation I can do with tests and deployment.

Hope this helps!